# capture click event from external source (child within parent) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using massrelevances polling feature. I include an embed code (below) which injects html into the webpage.

embed code from third-party

```
<div class="mr-space" data-space-id="project-id"></div>
<script src="//platform.massrelevance.com/js/massrel.js"></script>
<script>
  massrel.ui.load();
</script>
```

I want to capture a click event from the html that is injected from their embed code.

The only clicks it will register is when I set it to look within the body, which isn't practical, I need it to register a click within div.option-buttons

```
var link = {};

link.init = function() {
    $('.option-buttons').contents().on('click', function () {
      alert('clicked');
    });
}

window.onload = link.init;
```

html that is generated from the embed code above

```
<div class="option-buttons">
    <a href="">Vote</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The `on()` can filter out the event capturing to the desired element, making it very practical. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Its not clear but you can try

```
    $(document).on('click', '.option-buttons a', function () {
      alert('clicked');
    });
```

**EDIT**

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.